# How to select a range of the data in urls to views in Django

Tags: python, database, django-views, django-urls, python-re

```
path('<int:book_id>/',views.detail, name = 'detail')
```

How can I modify this line of code to can select the digits that can be used instead of sending any number?

as I want the range to be [1 - 5]

```
path('<int:book_id>[1-5]/',views.detail, name = 'detail'),
```

I've tried this but not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check it in the view itself.

```py
def detail(request, book_id):
    if book_id < 1 or book_id > 5:
        # do something here when the number is not between or equals 1-5.
        raise PermissionDenied()
```